# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium

I have some HTML with a dropdown list from a Booking Website, im trying to use Selenium to click on a value from the option group but getting

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-asset-path="/" data-domain="test_domain.com">
  <head>
    Hello
  </head>

  <h1>Test page</h1>

  <div class="player-select flex-grow relative">
  <select id="member_booking_form_player_2" name="member_booking_form[player_2]"
    ><option value="">Start typing to find player...</option
    ><optgroup label="General">
      <option value="-2">Guest</option
      ><option value="-3">Member not in list</option></optgroup
    ><optgroup label="You and your buddies">
      <option value="349">Player, One</option></optgroup
    ><optgroup label="Other club members">
      <option value="431">Fictional, Person</option
      ><option value="1846">Someone, Madeup</option></optgroup
    ></select>
</div>
</html>
```

**Function**

```
    def book_a_player_test(self, player_id, surname, first):

        # Use actionchains as it at least interacts with the dropdown
        player = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='member_booking_form_player_2'][@name='member_booking_form[player_2]']")
        ActionChains(self.browser).move_to_element(player).click().perform()  

        # Try to pick out the element
        select = Select(self.browser.find_element_by_id('member_booking_form_player_2'))
        #ways to handle drop down
        select.select_by_visible_text("Player, One")
```

Note - ive tried to combine the actionchains with the SELECT fucnctions but nothing works :-(

Im using Firefox with the latest geckodriver on a mac catalina

Answer (score 1):

Try below solutions to resolve yur issue with drop down handling option in your drop down is noot into scrolled view.

**Solution 1:**

```
selectElement = browser.find_element_by_id('member_booking_form_player_2')

ActionChains(self.browser).move_to_element(selectElement).perform()
dropdown = Select(selectElement)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='member_booking_form_player_2']//options[contains(.,'Fictional, Person')]"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Comment: `ActionChains` seems to prevent the error, yet is not selecting any of the elements from the dropdown

Comment: @PaulSyl1980 i have updated solution. Please have a look

Comment: Really appreciate your help, however im still struggling.  I've changed the original question to include the Test HTML and my function.

Comment: I have updated my solution can I request you to please check it and  if its noot working then please provide me your url

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, a combination of Actionchains to drop the menu and the option group, combined with Select_by_Visible.

```
    def book_a_player_test(self, player_id, surname, first):
        # Located and open the DropDown menu
        player = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='member_booking_form_player_2'][@name='member_booking_form[player_2]']/optgroup[@label='Other club members']")
        ActionChains(self.browser).move_to_element(player).click().perform()

        # Select the Element from the OptionGroup
        select = Select(self.browser.find_element_by_id('member_booking_form_player_2'))
        select.select_by_visible_text("Player, One")
```